# Ansible passing hash to include module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have problems to pass some composite data like a YAML mapping as input for the ansible include module.

Here is my test:

test.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    test_var:
      test1:
        hello: world
        hi: people
      test2:
        hello2: world2
        hi2: people2
  tasks:
    - debug: "msg='Variable item.value is: {{ item.value }}'"
      with_dict: "{{ test_var.test1 }}"
    - include: "test1.yml test_variable={{ item.value }}"
      with_dict: "{{ test_var.test1 }}"
```

test1.yml

```
---
- debug: "var={{ test_variable }}"
```

Here is the output. Notice the part with: `"people": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"`

```
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, test.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': u'people', 'key': u'hi'}) => {
    "item": {
        "key": "hi",
        "value": "people"
    },
    "msg": "Variable item.value is: people"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': u'world', 'key': u'hello'}) => {
    "item": {
        "key": "hello",
        "value": "world"
    },
    "msg": "Variable item.value is: world"
}

TASK [include] *****************************************************************
included: /home/mot/jira-scripts/ansible-playbooks/test1.yml for localhost
included: /home/mot/jira-scripts/ansible-playbooks/test1.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "people": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "world": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: FYI I got "ERROR: [DEPRECATED]: include + with_items is a removed deprecated feature.  Please update your playbooks." with ansible-playbook 1.9.3

Comment: I am using ansible 2.0.1 . This feature was readded back in ansible 2. It was deprecated in 1.6-1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the test1.yml file

`---
- debug: var=test_variable`

It works for me correctly.